# jquery - change background color on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose inside a document there are 4 label and I want the background become white when I click, but when I click another label, the previous label should back to its default (without using add class or remove class)

[image: screenshot of page]

https://s25.postimg.org/kb1m0re0f/screenshot_9.png

```
<header> 
     <label for="slide_trigger1">
        <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </label> 
     <label for="slide_trigger2"> 
        <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </label>  
      <label for="slide_trigger3">
         <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
      </label>  
      <label for="slide_trigger4"> 
         <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>  
      </label> 
</header>

<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(e) { 
        $('label').click(function() {  
            $(this).css({"background":"#fff","color":"green","border-radius":"100%" }); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Rather than adding image of JSBin share its URL

Answer (score 2):

Use `removeAttr()` method in jquery for removing the inline style in the lable element.

```
$('label').click(function(){  
 $('label').removeAttr('style');
 $(this).css({"background":"#fff","color":"green","border-radius":"100%" }); 
});
```

Comment: Glad it helps :-)